# Trying to sort object keys based on child property

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this object:

```
var myObject = {
    cat: {
        order: 1
    },

    mouse: {
        order: 4
    },

    dog: {
        order: 2
    },   

    shark: {
        order: 3
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get back: `["cat", "dog", "shark", "mouse"]`

I tried:

`_.sortBy(x, function(e) { return e.order} )`

Comment: First you need to get an array.

Comment: [_.keys](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#keys)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for it.

- get all the keys from the Object using `Object.keys()`.
- Simply sort all the keys by passing a custom `Comparator` to the sort function which compares the order property of the keys in the object.

```js
var myObject = { cat: { order: 1 }, mouse: { order: 4 }, dog: { order: 2 }, shark: { order: 3 } };

let result = Object.keys(myObject).sort((a,b)=> myObject[a].order -  myObject[b].order);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, worked well and I like I don't have to map at the end.

Answer (score 6):

use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) first, then sort by the **order** property of its second element (*because `Object.entries` returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property **[key, value]** pairs*), finally use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get what you need.

```js
var myObject = {
  cat: {
    order: 1
  },
  mouse: {
    order: 4
  },
  dog: {
    order: 2
  },
  shark: {
    order: 3
  }
}

console.log(
  Object.entries(myObject).sort((a, b) => {
    return a[1].order - b[1].order
  }).map(item => item[0])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var myObject = {
    cat: {
        order: 1
    },

    mouse: {
        order: 4
    },

    dog: {
        order: 2
    },   

    shark: {
        order: 3
    }
}     
let oKeys = Object.keys(myObject)

     let tempArray = []

     oKeys.forEach(function(key) {
        tempArray[myObject[key]['order']-1] = key
     })
          
   
     console.log(tempArray)
```

Comment: Why use `.map` when you are not using it for mapping functionality? This should be a `.forEach`. Then again, the body of the callback seems to be wrong, too.

Comment: You should consider making a runnable snippet so you can identify the errors it throws. hint: you probably want something more like: `tempArray[myObject[key].order -1] = key` (and forEach as vlaz mentioned)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @MarkMeyer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `lodash`.

Use `_.map` and `_.sort` for it.

- First, `_.map` to array of `order` and `name`.
- Then, `_.sort` and `_.map` `name`

By using lodash chain, make the code easy to read.

---

```
 _(myObject)
   .map((v, k) => ({order: v.order, name: k}))
   .sortBy('order')
   .map('name')
   .value()
```